# LibreOffice instances stop responding to keyboard after some time

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, libreoffice

**Problem:**
I am using LibreOffice Calc, Impress, and Writer.

*Sometimes* — usually after I have switched between LibreOffice and another program — after using one of these program for some time (can be 5 to 30 minutes), the window stops responding to my keyboard. Mouse is fine, but nothing happen if I type something/use shortcuts.

The issue seems to spread across concurrent LibreOffice instances: if I'm blocked in Impress, I cannot type anything in Calc neither.

The keyboard never resume responding (or, at least, it's not responding for many minutes), and the only way to solve the issue is to close all LibreOffice instances, and then, restart them.

**Question:**
How to get rid of this issue?

---

Install:

- Ubuntu: 18.04.2
- LibreOffice: Version: 6.0.7.3 – Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.6

Comment: Libreoffice periodically savesnbackup information about the currently being edited document. Are you sure that this is not a temporary lock out and after a few seconds you cannot resume using your keyboard again?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thanks for your suggestion. Indeed, it wasn't clear from my initial wording, but no: the keyboard is frozen for good: I can wait a few minutes and it's still not responding. Similarly, I can switch to another window and come back to LibreOffice again, and it's still not responding.

Comment: Ok. Can you try with another Ubuntu user? Did you look at system logs for any errors?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Yes I could install a new user. However, the issue is hard to reproduce and I cannot tell when it will occur. It can take up to an hour or so; plus it happens circa once ever 10 use or so.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Could you please indicate me where I could find relevant system/LibreOffice logs?

Comment: No idea actually. Since the problem may be related to disk, memory, library etc. errors, you can look at `/var/log/syslog` or `journalctl` at **exactly the time** the problem starts.